# Excel User search key word return summary found

Tags: excel, vba, search

I am attempting to create an excel spreadsheet quiz, that has enables users to enter into a cell/user form keywords/phrase to enable them to find relevant details and questions. An example of my spreadsheet content includes the following:

```html
<table border="1">
  <tr>
  <td>Category </td>
  <td>Question</td>
  <td> Answer</td>
    </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Fruit</td>
    <td>How many different types of apple trees are there?</td>
    <td>There are more than 7 493 kinds of different apple trees. At least 55 million tons of apples were grown around in the world in 2005. All together, they cost about $10 billion. China produced about 35% of the world's apples.</td>
    </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Vegetables </td>
    <td>How many different types of potatoes are there? </td>
    <td>There are literally thousands of different varieties of potatoes grown around the world. In the UK around 80 varieties are grown commercially. Below are some of the most popular potato varieties available in this country.</td>
    </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Juice</td>
    <td>What is juice?</td>
    <td>Juice is a liquid that is naturally contained in fruit and vegetables. </td>
</tr>
  <tr><td>Water</td>
    <td>What is the chemical formula for water? </td>
    <td>Water is made up of two elements, hydrogen and oxygen. Its chemical formula is H2O.</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

On a different tab, the user will be presented with the ability to type in a phrase ie 'potato'. I would like the user to be presented with questions and answers related to that phrase searched on a different tab.
Researching I have found search and look up functions but this only has enabled a value to be returned.

Can anyone advise a function/formula that would assist in this?

Comment: Is the data going to be laid out on a table in one sheet? or is it going to be generated by code.

If the former, you could just have a column(potentially hidden?) In which each unique product lies and use a VLOOKUP to return the matching results. There are other ways around it, but this would probably be one of the most efficient methods.

Comment: the table of information will be on one spreadsheet in the workbook. unclear what you mean by 'unique product'. i need the user to be able to enter a key phrase that they are searching for  rather than scrolling through what will be a massive table of categories/questions and answers. hope that clarifies what i am looking for here. many thanks

Comment: In the example table - it appears like there is a key for each item: Apple, Potato, Juice, Water.. That kind of thing. It would certainly be more consistent to lookup on the key for each line.

Otherwise, you may want to look at something like this - http://smallbusiness.chron.com/use-sql-statements-ms-excel-41193.html 

From what you are describing, an SQL statement might make some sense.

Comment: Thank you for this link - the data itself sits in the excel spreadsheet from what i understand this link provides information to import data from database using sql statement rather than running a search function through sql. The difficulty on relying on the 'key' is that the user may type in a different phrase they are looking for, i.e. oxygen. in this case it wouldnt find that 'water' was the correct key. i hope this makes sense?

Comment: Apologies, I cannot lay my hands on the correct link as it stands, but there is a (rather fiddly) method of using queries in Excel in this way. 

I understand your reason for not using keys, but can forsee a lot of problems with the complexity of queries you would want.

Other than using wildcard searches with index/match, I could only suggest maybe using a database to back onto the Excel Front End. This way you could use an ODBC connector to pull the desired results.